# Sqlalchemy delete orphaned relation with one-to-many

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two tables, `User` and `Profiles`. A user can have many profiles. If the user is deleted all the profiles are deleted. However I want to also make it so if a user has no profiles the user is also delete (assume I always insert a user with at least one profile).

I looked into delete-orphan but I'm not totally sure where I should put this or if it does what I need?

Any help is appreciated.
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/cascades.html#delete-orphan

```
class User(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean(), default=True, nullable=False)
    created_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=func.now(), nullable=False)
    profile_ = db.relationship("Profile", back_populates="user_", cascade="all,delete")


class Profile(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'profile'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False)
    user_ = db.relationship("User", back_populates="profile_")
```

Comment: I am not sure whether it is possible to delete User when the last profile is deleted using cascade mechanism. You probably have to write your own logic using events: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.SessionEvents.after_flush